# First week of the year belongs in December?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a small method in js that looks like this:

```
const getSelectWeekText = (weekNumber, year) => {
        let date = moment().year(year).week(weekNumber);
        let month = date.format('MMMM');

        return `Week ${weekNumber} (${month})`;
    };
```

Running example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/472uoLg8/

I dont understand why the first item in the result has Month of December? I expected it to be January.

Comment: 2021-01-01 was Friday of the last week of 2020 December. So maybe that's why you see December as first result. Try 2019. Its starts from January.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because different locales define week of year numbering differently, Moment.js added moment#week to get/set the localized week of the year.

Use `moment().isoWeek(weekNumber);`

```
const getSelectWeekText = (weekNumber, year) => {
        let date = moment().year(year).isoWeek(weekNumber);
        let month = date.format('MMMM');

        return `Week ${weekNumber} (${month})`;
    };
```

Refer to https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/.

Comment: That was it. Thank you.